# Extension Linq OrderBy

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an extension method to order in first place when a special condition is found.

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderFirstIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(i => predicate(i) ? 0 : 1);
    }
```

The usage is:

```
db.where(...).OrderFirstIf(i => i.Code == code).ThenBy(...).ToList();
```

However I got the exception "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities".

How to use the predicate in this extension method?

**Updated**

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderFirstIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
{
    return source.OrderBy(i => predicate(i) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

How to use the predicate in case of using Expression?

Comment: In that case, how will be the OrderBy(i => predicate(i) ? 0 : 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, predicate should be `<Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>`. But then you can't use `source.OrderBy(i => predicate(i) ? 0 : 1)` because it won't compile. The trick is to convert the predicate to a negated lambda expression:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderFirstIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
    Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
{
    var negated = Expression.Not(predicate.Body);
    var negatedLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(negated, predicate.Parameters);
    return source.OrderBy(negatedLambda);
}
```